# Array.indexOf() - of a document containing a field of given value [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How can I get Index of a document in an array containing only 1 given matching `key: value`?

for example if my array is

```js
[
    { name: 'abc', age: 17 },
    { name: 'xyz', age: 18 },
    { name: 'pqr', age: 19 },
]
```

now how can I get index of first document where `age: 18`?

I have tried

```js
list.indexOf({ age: 18 })
```

but this doesn't seem to work, it gives me `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
const arr = [
    { name: 'abc', age: 17 },
    { name: 'xyz', age: 18 },
    { name: 'pqr', age: 19 },
];
let idx = arr.findIndex(({age})=>age===18);
console.log(idx);
```